# How to display the multi line textAreas in lwuit (J2ME)?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have created a `TextArea` with statement ....

```
quest1Label = new TextArea();
```

I am using the `TextArea` for displaying the `Labels`.... So I use following function to set its properties....

```
private void setTextAreaProperty(TextArea textArea) {
    String textStr = textArea.getText();
    if (textArea.getStyle().getFont().stringWidth(textStr) > (width - 25)) {
        textArea.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
    } else {
        textArea.setSingleLineTextArea(true);
        textArea.setPreferredW(width);
    }
    textArea.setBorderPainted(false);
    textArea.setFocusable(false);
    textArea.setStyle(getPreviewStyle());
}
```

where **width = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();**
my problem is that up to two lines the label works properly but .... if the text is even larger it doesn't go to third line.
any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `TextArea` constructor like this `new TextArea(1, 20)` which allows the layout to "grow" more effectively.

The reason is mostly historic, LWUIT had a 3 column default for `TexAarea` which allow the `TexAarea` to shrink well but sucks when growing. The complexity in growing/shrinking is derived by the fact that layouts can be deeply nested and scrollable hence the available space vs. desired space calculation becomes recursive and at some hard to detect point unsolvable (infinite recursion).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [setGrowByContent](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/TextArea.html#setGrowByContent%28boolean%29)? Maybe the default number of rows is 2, and it doesn't grow more than that.

Regards.